# Design where image is centered in the left half of the screen with scale and move possibility

Tags: kivy

I have this design of the UI:
[image]

The hardest part is to center the image in the left half of the screen, with scale and move possibility. I'm trying to do it with `FloatLayout` and somehow combine the behavior of `Scatter` and `Image`.
I have this code sofar:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Tedegraph(App):
    def build(self):
        
        mainbox = FloatLayout()
        mainbox.add_widget(Button(text="Prev",
                                  font_size="17dp",
                                  size_hint=(.15, .15),
                                  pos_hint={"left":1,
                                            "center_y":0.5},
                                  ))
        #sp = Scatter(scale=1, do_scale = True, do_rotation = False, pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5})
        self.img = Image(source='img.png')
        #sp.add_widget(self.img)
        mainbox.add_widget(self.img) # images will change during execution

        self.text_label = Label(text="HELLO",  size_hint=(1, None), pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}) # text will change during execution
        self.text_label.bind(
          width=lambda *x: self.text_label.setter('text_size')(self.text_label, (self.text_label.width, None))) # only wrapping functionality
        mainbox.add_widget(self.text_label)
        mainbox.add_widget(Button(text="Next",
                                  font_size="17dp",
                                  size_hint=(.15, .15),
                                  pos_hint={"right":1,
                                            "center_y":0.5},
                                  ))
        return mainbox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tedegraph().run()
```

I hope it is possible with keeping the ratio of the image. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: You can probably use a Scatter, as already discussed, but it seems likely that you have something more specific in mind - what types of interaction do you want from the user, and within what bounds?

Comment: @inclement The answer of John Anderson is quite good but I have problem with Scatter positioning. It should be centered as the image is centered pos_hint={'center_x':0.33, 'center_y':0.5} in the default position (I can't achieve it) and then have the posibility to zoom (scale) and move to other location (the aim is to move it, when it collides with the text on a label).

Comment: @inclement Within what bounds? It would be nice if the image won't completelly vanish from the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size and position of the `Image` widget when you create it:

```
self.img = Image(source='img.png', size_hint=(0.33,0.33), pos_hint={'center_x':0.33, 'center_y':0.5}, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
```

And similarly, with the `Label`:

```
self.text_label = Label(text="HELLO\nThis is a Test", halign='center',  size_hint=(0.33, None), pos_hint={"center_x":0.67, "center_y":0.5})
```

Comment: Thank you and would you know how to combine it with Scatter to be possible for the image to scale (zoom) and move?

Comment: When I add the image to Scatter, the image is small and changed default position.

Comment: Can't help you there. I have never been able to get `Scatter` to work. Perhaps you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: I will create a bounty for this question. It is better than to create similar question.

Comment: I built upon your solution and have written solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651740/scatterlayout-do-translation-does-not-work/64652800#64652800). It seems to work, so far :-)